# NUnit 3.2: Autorun tests after compile (Windows)

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

On a new VS solution, I've started using NUnit 3.2. Older versions (2.6) had a external NUnit GUI, that made it possible to watch assemblies and automatically run tests on modifications. But I cannot find anything similar to this for 3.2 - neither in the docs nor through Google.

I've installed NUnit.3.2.0.msi, I've also installed the NUnit3 Test Adapter in VS + NUnit3.2 nuget package for my project.

I can easily run all my tests through VS' Test Explorer. But I miss some way to run them automatically. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In older versions of Visual Studio, there used to be an option to run tests after every build, but it was removed. It was always buggy and tended to lock files and prevent you from rebuilding.

You could set a post build command on your test project to automatically run NUnit console whenever your test project recompiles. You have NUnit console installed, so you could point to that, or use the NUnit.Runners package to install it into the packages folder of your solution.

Open your test project settings and go to the **Build Events** tab. Click on **Edit Post-Build**. Enter the following;

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "$(TargetPath)"`

[image: VS PRoject Settings]

Now, whenever you build, your tests will be run and the results will appear in the output window.

[image: Tests in Output]

Maybe not ideal if there is a lot of build output after your tests but it works.

FYI, the colour in the build output is a side-effect of the [VSColorOutput Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496), it is not from NUnit.

Visual Studio captures STDOUT, so I haven't been able to get it to open a CMD window and run the tests. If anyone knows how to do that, add a comment and I will update.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI for NUnit 3 under developement on GitHub - but it's not advised for production use yet.

We set our tests up using the [NUnitLite runner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/). This allows you to turn your test assembly into an executable - and on run, will launch the console and run all tests. [[Documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner)]

Comment: Thanks for the info on NUnitLite, but am I correct in assuming, that it does not run automatically on compile? Also I have multiple test-projects in my solution, one per actual project.

Comment: @Carsten How do you mean "run on compile", sorry? If you hit F5, it will run your tests, yes.

Comment: Problem is, that I have multiple test-projects in the solution. And your suggestion will AFAICS only run the project set as Startup project.

Comment: Yes - that is true. Rob's suggestion sounds like the way to go!